# Why does work done for polarization per unit volume contain $1\over 2$as in $\frac{1}{2} \mathbf E\cdot \mathbf P?$

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, polarization

Work done per unit volume to change the polarization from $0$ to $\bf P$ is given as the integral of $\mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf P'$ as $$u_p= \int_0^{\bf P}\mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf P' \;$$ integrating which it gives \begin{align}u_p&=\mathbf E\int_0^{\bf P} d\mathbf P'\\&= \mathbf E\;( \mathbf P')|_0^{\bf P}\\&= \mathbf E\cdot \mathbf P \end{align}

So, how did $1\over 2$ come in the relation above?

But Feynman did this otherwise; he included $1\over 2$ as is written in this excerpt from his [lecture](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_31.html#Ch31-S3):

> [...] the work per unit volume is found to be
>   $$\boldsymbol{E}⋅d\boldsymbol{P}.$$
>   Since the magnitude of $\boldsymbol P$ is proportional to $\boldsymbol E,$ the work done per unit volume in bringing the polarization from $0$ to $\boldsymbol P$ is the integral of $\boldsymbol E⋅d\boldsymbol P.$ Calling this work $u_P$, we write
>   $$u_P=\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol E⋅\boldsymbol P=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i E_iP_i$$ [...]

Where did $1\over 2$ come from? I'm not getting that.

Comment: Does the content you cite come from The Feynman physics lectures ?

Comment: @StephenWong: Yes: Link:http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_31.html#Ch31-S3

Comment: $\vec{P}\propto\vec{E}$, i.e. $\vec{P}=\alpha\vec{E}$. Then $\mathrm{d}W=\vec{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{P}=\alpha E\mathrm{d}E$ and thus $W=\frac{\alpha}{2} E^2$ by integration. Plugging $\vec{P}$ back in gives you the result

Comment: @Bort: Write it as an answer instead.

Comment: @Bort You are right, the electric field is a function of polarization here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\textbf{E}\equiv \textbf{E}(\textbf{P})$ one cannot pull it out of the integral sign.

Using the correct relation $E^i = \alpha^i_{\phantom{i}j}\,P^j$ and replacing the before within the integral sign gives back the $1/2$ after integration.

Comment: Could you tell why have you written $i$ as exponent?

Comment: Because the components of the vectors (on a certain basis) transform contravariantly and thus, according to the standard notations, their indeces appear as superscripts.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I didn't get that 'contravariant'; guess it's related to tensors as I'm reading the chapter where Feynman introduces tensor & its application in a brief manner. Nevertheless, I got what you want to say.